# usage of the word "sweet memory"

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to use to describe an event in the recent past as "sweet memory" or should it be used only if the event has occured very long?

Comment: Interesting. The words themselves don't require a large intervening span, but *memory* used in that context does carry that connotation.

Comment: But you could say, “Our trip to the park yesterday will be a sweet memory for years to come.”

Comment: ok.but can i use it while sharing some pictures of an event that has happened a week ago and say "my sweet memories"?